# Form submit fails on second time submit

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Hello I am working on wordpress and below is my php code. I show images by fetching their path from database and have a vote button with every image and when it is clicked the vote is added to the votes table. After vote is added I want to show that queue of images again with updated votes for all the images. I am doing this successfully but when I press vote button for the second time to add second vote I get a message that database insertion failed. Below is my code and snapshot of how my page looks and what is the error are all mentioned below. Images are comming from articles table which has 1:N relationship with votes table.

PHP Code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $ccc = $_POST['comp'];
        $cat =$_POST['category'];   
        global $wpdb;

        $compp = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT competition FROM competition ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1");
        $userid = $_POST['id'];
        $myvote = 1;

    if($wpdb->insert(
        'zvotes',
        array(
                'zvotes' => $myvote,
                'zcompetition' => $compp,
                'aid' => $userid
            )
) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'your vote was successfully recorded';
//show the updated results


//get current competition value



      $sqll = "SELECT articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title, Sum(zvotes.zvotes) AS votessum FROM articles LEFT JOIN zvotes on articles.aid=zvotes.aid WHERE articles.category = '$cat' && articles.competition = '$ccc' GROUP BY articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title  ORDER BY votessum";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sqll)) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<input name='category' type='hidden' value='$result->category'>";
echo $result->title.'<br>';
echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>';
echo $result->body.'<br>';
echo "<input name='comp' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
echo $result->username.'<br>';

echo $result->votessum.'<br>';
echo "<input style='margin-bottom:30px;' value='vote' name='submit' type='submit'/></form>";    

}//end of foreach



}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// drop down
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="category" id="category" style="width:250px; background-color:lightgrey;">';
echo    '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" ">Select category</option>';
echo   '<option value="My Testimony">My Testimony</option>';
echo    '<option value="Love & Relationships">Love & Relationships</option>';
echo    '<option value="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>';
echo '</select>'; 
echo    '<input type="submit" name="a" value="Search"  style="margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px;">';
echo '</form>';


//show after drop down value is selected
if(isset($_POST['a'])){
//echo "zeeshanaslamdurrani". "<br>";

echo do_shortcode('[ujicountdown id="Photos Contest" expire="2015/04/30 00:00" hide="true" url="" subscr="sdf" recurring="" rectype="second" repeats=""]');
      global $wpdb;
//get current competition value
$cat =$_POST['category'];
        $comp = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT competition FROM competition ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1");
//echo $comp;

      $comp = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT competition FROM competition ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1");
            echo "current competition is ". $comp;


      $sqll = "SELECT articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title, Sum(zvotes.zvotes) AS votessum FROM articles LEFT JOIN zvotes on articles.aid=zvotes.aid WHERE articles.category = '$cat' && articles.competition = '$comp' GROUP BY articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title  ORDER BY votessum";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sqll)) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<input name='category' type='hidden' value='$result->category'>";
echo "<input name='id' type='hidden' value='$result->aid'>";

echo $result->title.'<br>';
echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>';
echo $result->body.'<br>';
echo "<input name='comp' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
echo $result->username.'<br>';

echo $result->votessum.'<br>';
echo "<input style='margin-bottom:30px;' value='vote' name='submit' type='submit'/></form>";    

}//end of foreach




}//end of isset
```

My page
[image]

After vote(which is a form submit button) is pressed once
[image]

Error on second pressing vote button second time after page refresh
[image]

votes table
[image]

Articles table (articles table has 1 to many relationship with votes table)
[image]

Comment: check by mysql_error & solve..

Comment: how can use that in wordpress please guide how I should modify my insert query code ... thanks

Comment: when you are presenting the result of query with die, write there echo mysql_error(), after the error will be shown you will be able to track...

Comment: ok I have added that but the insert works for one time but second time no error is shown and an empty page is returned. This is my query now if($wpdb->insert(
        'zvotes',
        array(
                'zvotes' => $myvote,
    'zcompetition' => $compp,
    'aid' => $userid
            )
) == false) wp_die(mysql_error());

Comment: You can't post same data in wordpress untill unless you don't reload your page not refresh. Try submitting the form after reload tha page.

Comment: echo the error dear..read the comment above. Also have a view to get the error either by echoing the error or query to run on back end...

Comment: look insert query works for the first time and I have used mysql_error () but it returns an empty screen and the page width also gets reduced. And I am using a page template in wordpress ... what can be wrong

Comment: error is not showing I have mysql_error() as stated by you DevLakshman